# Bootstrap, how to 'include' navigation bar and footer without server side code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been dabbling with some Twitter Bootstrap recently and have been enjoying it.

All the tutorials and videos out there only seem to show how to use it for so called single paged sites.

I would like to create a predominantly static, multi page site, essentially still pure HTML. Though, for this there is alot of code that I would be re-using, i.e. nav bar, footer, etc, but I would like to keep the code following DRY.

I remember many many years ago you would use iframes and such, but I do recall that any CSS styling would be lost during this 'include'.

I have been searching for some time, but the only thing that seems to pop up is PHP, and things such as Handlebars, Moustashe, etc...though these seem to be a little too complex for my requirements. I have also looked at jQuery Clone.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If using Dreamweaver you can create a template for the site. In the template have the nav area and footer area as not editable. Then each new page ie Home About Portfolio and contact then create new from template and the code will be the same for each page. You then just change the content in the main section.

Not sure if this was your goal. If not please elaborate.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, I suppose what I am after is some guidance in regards to client side templating(?) if thats even at all possible.

I didnt want to have to go down the route of having to create a fully blown php/server side implementation just for the sake of keeping my code DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side include:

Use this html tag wherever you need to include your reusable code (nav bar, footer, ...)

```
<!--#include file="footer.html" -->
```

You files must have the extension .shtml so the web server would know that it needs to process the include tag fist before constructing the response

Comment: I had tried this route since posting the question. It partially works for my solution. I ideally did not want to use this path, but it may be the only way for the moment.